# Need help in modifying the design

Tags: arduino-uno, accelerometer

I am planning to do a project on Sequential tilt motion lock using Arduino uno and accelerometer. I would like to present the accelerometer **within** a rotatable object. So what other components do i have to add to be able to do it i.e.. for wireless transmission of data from the object(that has the acc. meter) to the Uno board. [image: Tilt lock circuit]

Comment: Seems to do the trick already. What else do you need?

Comment: @Gerben i would like to perform the task wirelessly..

Comment: So then add a wireless serial module.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams i am a absolute beginner to electronics and stuff. So if you can suggest a component that will be good for me to purchase and try and do the project.

Comment: @SomasundharamSampath There are hundreds of different modules and frequencies available. With what do you wish to control it?

Comment: The basic idea of the project is to have a unconventional key to doors.. So i thought of fixing the arduino board to the door and have a portable object within which the acc. meter will be placed... So to give signal to the arduino board from acc. meter i require a wireless module (range:less than 30 meters is sufficient i guess)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do a google search for "arduino wireless serial" you'll get several results. Plugging them into the arduino should be trivial. Most suppliers (other than ebay) will also have examples for you to reference where it comes to coding your project to use the module.

You should also be aware that you will usually need a transceiver, and a receiver.

You might take a look into the XBEE solutions, as they appear to be popular.